# Limit Number of attachments with Java on a SharePoint new form item?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I'm currently using this bit of code in a content editor on the newform in a sharepoint list to check and make sure there is an attachment on a new item form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function PreSaveAction() { if 
(document.getElementById('idAttachmentsRow').style.display=='none' ) { > 
alert('Attachment is Mandatory! Please attach Documents.'); return false ; } 
else { return true; } } </script>
```

Is there anyway to use some similar code to make sure a user only uploads 1 attachment and not multiples?

Bonus question:  Is there a simple method to either set a column value when a user changes/upload a different/new attachment or replaces the current one atatched to a sharepoint list item?

Answer (score 0):

Try below js solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function PreSaveAction() {            
                var attachementCount=$('#idAttachmentsTable').find('tr').length;
                if (attachementCount < 1) {
                    alert("Attachment is Mandatory!");
                    return false;
                } else
                    return true;            
            }
        </script>
```